# Can Lilypond chordmode be made to recognize inversions?

Tags: lilypond, chord-inversions

There are times when it's convenient for me to write something like:

```
<< e a c >>
```

or

```
\chordmode { e:1.4.6- }
```

in my harmony.  In staff notation, everything's find, but when I engage Lilypond's chordnames, it comes out as E♭6sus4 and not the clearer Am/E.

Is there a way to make Lilypond recognize this chord and use the clearer description?  I'd rather not have to rewrite the source text.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different ways to enter chords in LilyPond.

These will all come out the same on a `staff` (because it is easy for LilyPond to convert the various notations into notes).

But `chordNames` cannot be expected to recognise/guess the intended 'tonic' of the chord; you'll have to spell it out one way or another:

```
myChords = \chordmode {
    <e' a' c''>1    %  this doesn't work
    <a' c'' e'>     %  it'd be nice if this worked, but it doesn't

    e:1.4.6-        %  this doesn't work, as the wrong tonic is specified
    a:1.3-.5/e      %  this works, but is cumbersome, and kinda ugly to type

    a:min/e         %  this method is simple, logical, and effective
}

<<
    \new ChordNames {
        \myChords
    }

    \new Staff {
        \myChords
    }
>>
```

[image: five versions of the same chord]